# ETL between a MySQL primary Data Store and a MongoDB secondary Data Store

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, etl, data-synchronization

We have a rails app that has a MySQL backend, each client has one DB and the schema is identical. We use a custom gem to change the DB based on the URL of the request (This is some legacy code that we are trying to move away from)

We need to capture some changes from those MySQL databases (Changes in inventory, some order information, etc) transform and store in a single MongoDB database (multitenant data store), this data will be used for analytics at first, but our idea is to move everything there.

There was something in place to do this, using AR callbacks and Rabbit, but to be honest it wasn't working correctly and it looked like it was more trouble to fix it than to start over with a fresh approach.

We did some research and found some tools to do ETL but they are overkill for our needs.

Does anyone have some experience with a similar problem?

Recommendations on how to architect and implement this simple ETL

Answer (score 2):

Pentaho provides change-data-capture option which can solve Data-synchronization problems.

If by Overkill you mean Setup, Configuration, then Yes that is the common problem with ETL tools and PENTAHO is the easiest among them.

If you can provide more details, I'll be glad to provide an elaborate answer.